# subprocess.call() doesn't throw and error when file is not found

Tags: python, django, web

I'm trying to run a python script from a Django web service and I'm using the subprocess.call() method and I've put it in a try except block because I need to get the error when something is wrong. I discovered that when the path to the script is not valid is not raising an error it's only displaying it on the console, but I need it to be thrown so I can catch it in the except block.

Here is my code.

```
try:
    row = exec_SQL(f"SELECT [ID], [ProjectPath], [MainFileName] FROM [dbo].[WebserviceInfo] WHERE ProjectName='{project}'")
        command = f'python {row[1]}\{row[2]} {model} {scenario}'
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    error_message = str(e)
```

This is the path to the file + some arguments that I need.

```
f'python {row[1]}\{row[2]} {model} {scenario}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the file exists, before trying to execute the script. If there is no such file, you could raise an Exception yourself.

Something like:

```py
import os.path

if not os.path.isfile('script.py'):
    raise Exception('File not found')
```